# Debug error while running 2 threads of functions with random generators in them

Tags: c++, debugging

Trying to learn threading, random (and then transfer of random numbers between threads). While running program got an error from debugger - thread has exited with code 3 (0x3) (but program runs as intended, showing random generated numbers).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>

void func1 ()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::random_device iRNG1;
        std::mt19937 rRNG1(iRNG1());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rd1 (0, 6);
        int num1 {rd1(rRNG1)};
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << "Thread1: " << num1 << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds (500));
        
    }

};

void func2 ()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds (250));
    while (true) 
    {
        std::random_device iRNG2;
        std::mt19937 rRNG2(iRNG2());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rd2 (2,4);
        int num2 {rd2(rRNG2)};
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << "Threaddddddd2: " << num2 << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds (500));

    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::thread t1 (func1);
    std::thread t2 (func2);
    return 0;
}
```

I dont even know where to start, because everything seems fine. Is it because I am identifying twice the random generator on both threads? edit: nope, that wasnt the case, updated the code. Edited out the random generator - problem somewhere else.

Comment: The threads never complete, so when `main` exits you get an error. For a quick hack, add `t1.detach(); t2.detach();` after creating the threads. For a real fix, don't write threads that run forever. Then you can call `t1.join(); t2.join();` in `main` for an orderly termination.

Comment: Independent of the threading problem, don't create on-off random number generators. Create each generator exactly once, and call it each time you need a new number. In the code in the question, move the creation of `rd1` and `rd2` and their predecessors so that they're created **before** entering the loop.

Comment: @pete-becker But what if I want these threads to exactly go forever till a stop via command?

Comment: You can either detach the threads, which is almost always a coding hack to "fix" a design mistake, or you can provide a mechanism to tell the threads that they should finish whatever they're doing and quit. `main` is special in C++; when the program returns from `main` everything is supposed to be finished.

Comment: Use `std::jthread` or wait for threads properly.